# Use javascript substring to specify character length

Tags: javascript, html

I have a heading on my webpage that I want to limit to a certain number of characters. The 
heading is for a blog post so the title changes. This is essentialy what I want to accomplish.

```
<body>

   <script>
    var x= document.getElementById("entry-title");
    document.write(x.substring(0,10));
   <script> 

    <h1 id="entry-title">This is a sample blog title</h1>

</body>
```

Comment: Won't `x.innerText = x.substring(0,10);` do what you want?

Comment: Using `innerText` will fail in Firefox.  Either use jQuery or another library that covers up these differences, or feature-detect for the usage of `textContent` instead of `innerText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that

```
 <body>

   <script>
   window.onload = 
   function (){
    var x= document.getElementById("entry-title");
    x.innerText = x.innerText.substring(0,10);
    }
   </script> 




    <h1 id="entry-title">This is a sample blog title</h1>



</body>
```

There the code with jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>

   <script>

       $(document).ready(

       function (){
           var text = $("#entry-title").text();
           var x= $("#entry-title").text(text.substring(0,10));
       }
    );
   </script> 

    <h1 id="entry-title">This is a sample blog title</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1 id="entry-title">This is a sample blog title</h1>
<script>
(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("entry-title"),
        supportedProp = el.textContent != null ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

    el[supportedProp] = el[supportedProp].substring(0, 10);
}());
</script>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ahoyob/2/edit)

You have to either place your script below the element that you want to reference or defer its execution with a `DOMContentLoaded` or window `load` event handler.

Also, the W3C standard property is `textContent` instead of IE's proprietary (and adopted by Chrome) `innerText` property. Therefore you need to do some feature detection if you want to support both Firefox and IE. Chrome accepts either of the properties.